# Doctrine resolve_target_entities in custom bundle configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've made a Symfony 3 bundle which has abstract Models for further extendability. Something like **User** model in FOS\UserBundle. But, unlike FOS's Bundle, my needs also to have relationships between these Models\Entities. I've managed to do that by Interfaces and Doctrine little bit (hehe, almost byte) of configuration. So, for now, I have to do 2 things to configure - let's say - My\CustomBundle.

In app/config/config.yml I must add:

```
[...]
doctrine:
    orm:
[...]
        resolve_target_entities:
            My\CustomBundle\Model\Entity1Interface: AppBundle\Entity\Entity1
            My\CustomBundle\Model\Entity2Interface: AppBundle\Entity\Entity2
[...]
```

And also My\CustomBundle configuration:

```
my_custom:
    doctrine:
        entity_1_class: AppBundle\Entity\Entity1
        entity_2_class: AppBundle\Entity\Entity2
```

As You can see, the configurations is a bit messy and repetitive because of the doctrine.orm section. I wish I could avoid it by doing it automatically in My\CustomBundle. Is there any possibility to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with help of compiler pass. Add compiler pass that will change `resolve_target_entities` according to `my_custom` bundle config.

**CompilerPass:**

```
namespace My\CustomBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Doctrine\ORM\Version;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class DoctrineResolveTargetEntityPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // resolve_target_entities
        $definition = $container->findDefinition('doctrine.orm.listeners.resolve_target_entity');

        $definition->addMethodCall('addResolveTargetEntity', array(
            $container->getParameter('my_custom.doctrine.entity_1.resolve_from'), // My\CustomBundle\Model\Entity1Interface
            $container->getParameter('my_custom.doctrine.entity_1.resolve_to'), // AppBundle\Entity\Entity1
            array(),
        ));

        if (version_compare(Version::VERSION, '2.5.0-DEV') < 0) {
            $definition->addTag('doctrine.event_listener', array('event' => 'loadClassMetadata'));
        } else {
            $definition->addTag('doctrine.event_subscriber', array('connection' => 'default'));
        }
    }
}
```

And register this compiler pass in your bundle

```
namespace My\CustomBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\PassConfig;
use My\CustomBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineResolveTargetEntityPass;

class MyCustomBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new DoctrineResolveTargetEntityPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. And is there any possibility to do that with doctrine.dbal.types? I also use two custom enum types in my bundle and I also want them to be automatically injected into app after enabling my bundle.

Comment: do You have any idea how can I achieve this trick with doctrine.dbal.types? I can't see any event listener accurate for that in Doctrine

Comment: I can't say, I didn't have custom types in bundles.